# Wordpress Custom Post Type Permalink

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, permalinks

http://synergymediaprojects.co.uk/nda/edu-course/diploma/a-guide-for-beginners/

I have a structure of this url on the themes I bought, course is a custom post type, diploma on the url is the a category, every time I add a new course post "edu-course" is already embedded on the permalink.

How should I be able to remove the "edu-course" on the permalink?